# Firebase Analytics for TVOS

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, tvos, firebase-analytics, apple-tv

I am using google analytics in my Apple TV app. Now, I want to switch it to Firebase analytics. But I found that firebase doesn't officially supports tvos.

Does anybody knows workaround for this. I want to implement just the analytics part of firebase sdk.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can find your answer here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/10

Answer (score 0):

As of the 8.9.0 release, Firebase has official beta support for tvOS, including Analytics.